# JaxB custom writer with line breaks and no indentation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, formatting

I have a java app outputting XML. I use the RI implementation of JaxB for that.

Thing is, one of the third-party apps consuming my output does not read the file as XML, but line by line, and unmarshals it in it's own, twisted way. After much questionning, it was deemed I had to adapt.

So my objective is to produce XML looking like this:

```
<root>
<alice>
<bob>
bobContent
</bob>
</alice>
</root>
```

It's line breaks between each node, and *encasing node contents*, no indentation. 
I find it quite distressing, but it's what was asked.

So, my idea was to create my own implementation of **XMLStreamWriter**, and let it handle that.

**Is it a good idea or am I missing a simpler solution? Could you provide good pointers about how to write a custom XMLStreamWriter and common pitfalls?**

Comment: If you want line breaks around text content then you'll have to put them there yourself in the properties being marshalled - `alice.setBob("\nbobContent\n")` - the formatter can adjust _ignorable_ whitespace but it shouldn't touch significant whitespace.

Comment: I would use your custom `XMLStreamWriter` approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a `Transformer` to achieve this. Basically you can post process the marshalled output:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// 0) make sure to disable formatted output
final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance({YOURCLASS}.class);
final Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, false);

// 1) marshal to byte array
final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(this, out);
out.flush();

// 2) setup properties for post processing
final indent = 0;
Transformer transformer = SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", 0);

// 3) write it to the file
Source xmlSource = new SAXSource(new org.xml.sax.InputSource(input));
final FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream("filename.xml");
StreamResult res = new StreamResult(fos);
transformer.transform(xmlSource, res);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```